# KineticJS: Destroyed shape still listens for events

Tags: kineticjs

I tried to destroy a shape by clicking on it but after it is destroyed the mouseleave event handler of this shape is still being fired (errors in console). I assumed that KineticJS would unbind all events of a destroyed a shape. So basically the question is if i have to manually disable all event listeners from a shape if i want to destroy it in KineticJS.

Here is the link to jsfiddle and the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/evNyp/8/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

// dashed line
var greenLine = new Kinetic.Line({
    points: [73, 70, 340, 23, 450, 60, 500, 20],
    stroke: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 10,
    lineJoin: 'round',
    dashArray: [10, 5],
    dashArrayEnabled: false
});

layer.add(greenLine);
stage.add(layer);

greenLine.on('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log('enter');
    this.setDashArrayEnabled(true);
    this.getLayer().draw();
});

greenLine.on('mouseleave', function() {
    console.log('leave');
    this.setDashArrayEnabled(false);
    this.getLayer().draw();
});

greenLine.on('click', function() {
    //this.off('mouseleave');
    this.destroy();
    layer.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call greenLine.destroy() from outside the greenLine.on event handlers.

The reason:  You can't destroy something that's currently in scope (greenLine's event handler is still in scope).

For example, you could listen for clicks on the stage and destroy greenLine in that event handler.

```
$(stage.getContent()).on('click', function (event) {
    greenLine.destroy();
    layer.draw();
});
```

Here is a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/BVyNF/

Comment: I updated the fiddle and destroyed the shape in the click event of the layer using its tagetNode property but still got the same error: http://jsfiddle.net/evNyp/10/
Is it still in the scope even if i use the event handler of the layer?

Comment: KineticJS does not listen for clicks on the transparent part of a layer (yes, I know the Docs imply that it does).  And clicking on greenLine does trigger layer.on("click",...) but also triggers the greenLine event handlers which calls greenLine into scope at the very time you're try to destroy it.  Instead, for example, grab a reference to the stage container and listen for clicks there.  Alternatively, in greenLine-on-click you could call an async function like setTimeout which would destroy greenLine after a small delay to let it go out of scope.

Comment: I found another workaround by putting the greenline into a group and removing the group. I am not really sure why it is working that way but no errors are thrown. Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/evNyp/12/

Comment: Yep...as long as the object is not trying to delete itself, you're OK--as you've discovered, a group works too.    ;)